# add to List in Scala

Tags: scala

I created Graph and Edge classes.

I try to add edge object to list, but it does not affect:

```
class Graph (){
  val edges = List()
  def add_edge(edge: Edge): Unit = {
    this.edges.->(edge)
  }

  def get_edges(): List[Edge] = {
    this.edges
  }
}

class Edge(var n1: Int, var n2: Int) {

}

object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val edge = new Graph.Edge(2,4);
    val graph = new Graph()
    graph.add_edge(edge)
    println(graph)
  }
}
```

What is the problem? How can I add the Edge to to the list in Scala?

Comment: Are you using mutable or immutable lists?

Comment: First, `->`  doesn't add an element to a list, it just creates a tuple, you want `:+` - Second, note that appending elements to a **List** is very expensive, so you may want to use another collection. - Third, most importantly all those operations return modified copies of the data, instead of mutating it, so you probably need either a mutable variable, or a mutable collection or re-structure your algorithm to do not need mutability. - Finally, to answers your question the problem is that you are trying to use a new language without even doing a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using immutable lists here, you could do:

```scala
class Graph (){
  var edges: List[Edge] = List[Edge]()
  def add_edge(edge: Edge): Unit = {
    this.edges = edge :: this.edges
  }

  def get_edges(): List[Edge] = {
    this.edges
  }
}

class Edge(var n1: Int, var n2: Int) { }

object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val edge = new Edge(2,4)
    val graph = new Graph()
    graph.add_edge(edge)
    println(graph.edges)
  }
}
```

Output:

```scala
List(uk.co.santander.capitaltools.filesharing.UtilsTest$$anonfun$1$Edge$1@5a63f509)
```

The operator `::` will prepend the new edge to the beginning of the list. Since the list is immutable, it will not create a new copy, and will reuse the original list as the tail for the new one. It is an O(1) operation.

Also, notice that I have change `val edges ...` to `var edges ...` since you will be creating new `List` objects every time to prepend a new `edge`.

As @Luis Miguel mentioned in the comment, you should do a basic tutorial, read the getting started documentation, etc. Since you seem to be missing the basics of Scala.

You can start here:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html

And, about immutable lists: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/list-class.html

In this case, you may well consider mutable lists, so check this: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

The reasons why your `add_edge` does not work is described in the comment.

I just want to reiterate, that `List` and other collections in scala are *immutable* by default, because this is "the scala way". You should adopt this pattern too in order to write good and idiomatic scala code.

Just pretend that `var` and mutable structures don't exist at all for a while, until you get a good enough grip on the language to be able to recognize the (rare) situations when they are actually necessary.

```
case class Graph (edges: List[Edge] = Nil) {
   def addEdge(edge: Edge) = Graph(edge :: edges)
}
case class Edge(n1: Int, n2: Int) 

object Main{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val edge = Edge(2,4);
    val graph = Graph().addEdge(edge)
    println(graph)
  }
}
```